# SQL: INSERT + SET - Standard or MySQL specific?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I got used to the following INSERT standard possible with MySQL. Now I ask myself, if this is standard or is it MySQL specific. Can some practically verify if for example Oracle, JavaDB / Derby and of cause PostgreSQL can handle the INSERT statement this way:

```
INSERT INTO myTabe SET 'name' ='myName', number_of_children = 12;
```

This looks way better than insert values etc.

I often find only the INSERT INTO VALUES syntax so I am unsure if INSERT INTO SET syntax is standard conform beside I like it best.

Comment: use **update tbl SET**

Comment: This is an invention of the MySql developers. Very confusing one imho.

Comment: I like it better than this INSERT VALUES... makes no sense.

Comment: @Klin would you like to do your comment in an answer so I can give you a green marker for this?

Comment: Just for my knowledge, can someone explain why someone would down-vote this question? Just curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `INSERT ... SET ...` is specific for MySql and rather unknown in other RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql `update`

```
update myTabe SET name ='myName', number_of_children = 12;
```

Comment: Update does not do an insert... :-)